Use Web3 in React but encountered nth-check vulnerability
I am trying to use web3 in React but keep running into nth-check vulnerability when I try to install web3 packages. After googling I realized that this has been a common problem and can usually be ignored since it will never be triggered from the user end. However, this issue stops me from installing web3 and I am not sure how I can ignore it in this case.
Warnings are shown as follows:

What I have tried:

Move 'react-scripts' into 'devDependencies' and run npm audit --production. (Same vulnerabilities were found)
Run npm audit fix and npm audit fix --force. (Even more vulnerabilities were found)

Related posts tried but failed:

github Dependabot alert: Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check
React NPM inefficient regular expression complexity in nth-check

I tried the same thing last year and everything went smoothly. I wonder how I can get rid of these and import web3 in my React project. Really appreciated if anyone could help me on this and thanks in advance!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image with the plain text of your warnings, and make sure you include a [mcve]?  Note that "web3" as a blockchain-related term has pretty much nothing to do with the World Wide Web, and standard Web frameworks like React wouldn't normally interact with it.

The Web3 library is installed correctly, but you’re seeing warnings about vulnerabilities in its subdependencies. These issues are the responsibility of the library maintainers, so you don’t need to resolve them yourself.
You can continue building your app, and the vulnerabilities should be addressed in future library updates.
So you just run:
npm install web3

And go back to building your dApp.
